# Zinnia Blog doesn't use custom auth user model

Tags: django, zinnia

I am using Zinnia Blog module with my Django app. I have a Django app and have a custom User model. I have added the following setting:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.Member'
```

However, when I try to create a new entry in the blog I get the Foreign Key constraint error.

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
(1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`example`.`zinnia_entry_authors`, CONSTRAINT `author_id_refs_id_410656e2874b02ff` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`))')
```

It references the default auth model (which doesn't exist in the database) instead of the specified auth model. How do make Zinnia use the correct table.

Thanks.

Comment: Which Zinnia version are you using?

Comment: From the git source https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia

Comment: Did you start with a fresh database after you have introduced the new `AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Comment: Yes. There's already records in the custom user model. I didn't use the default auth model right from the start

Comment: Try with a new one :) The integrity error seems to tell that there are still some constraints referencing Django's model in the author table defined...